# Getting the size of an array in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, count

I would like some help with getting the size of an array inside an object:

```
var st = { "itema":{...},"itemb":[{"id":"s01","cd":"c01","dd":"d01",....}{"id":"s02","cd":"c02","dd":"d02",....}]}
```

How would you get a count of the objects inside `"itemb"` (in this case 2)?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Javascript arrays have a length property. Use it like this:

```
st.itemb.length
```

Comment: That should be `st.itemb.length`

Answer (score 19):

Arrays have a property `.length` that returns the number of elements.

```
var st =
    {
        "itema":{},
        "itemb":
        [
            {"id":"s01","cd":"c01","dd":"d01"},
            {"id":"s02","cd":"c02","dd":"d02"}
        ]
    };

st.itemb.length // 2
```